# Need help on Informatica Scenario

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need your help. I have to work on two scenarios -

- There is a informatica workflow WF1 which we need to invoke at
  8PM. This worflow will look for a file (ETL.txt) and if this file
  will not come in another 1hour (9PM), then it will get fail and send
  mail to support person.If file come on time, then it will run.
- In a mapping the source flat file's field separator is comma (,)
  and if tomorrow this field separator get change to pipe (|), then how
  we can accomodate the change in worfkow. Is it a way that dynamically
  we can identity the flat file field separator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file through unix script and pass the value of the same to the workflow.Based on the result,you can move